# Spring framework design with interfaces

Tags: java, spring

I have a Java Spring application designed as below:

```
public interface A{
  method A;
  method B;
}

Class ACon implements A{

}

public interface B{
  method A;
  method B;
}

Class BCon implements B{

}
```

Now I have 2 methods which are common - say methX and methY which can be common to both classes ACon and BCon. They both use same Autowired instances. How can I fit in methX and methY without repeating then in ACon and BCon ?

Comment: What do you mean by a "common method"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a base class with "common" implementation for the methods and make sure ACon and BCon extends the base class:

```
class BaseCon {
    public void methodX (){
    ...
    }

    public void methodY (){
    ...
    }
}

class ACon  extends BaseCon implements A{
...
}

class ACon  extends BaseCon implements A{
...
}
```